# LINQ List gives null exception in where Clause

Tags: c#, exception, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects, where-clause

```
var q = from p in query
where 
   ((criterias.birthday == p.BirthDay|| criterias.birthday == null))                                
&& ((criterias.marriageDate == null || criterias.marriageDate == p.MarriageDate))                                
&& ((criterias.gender == p.Gender) || (criterias.gender == null))
&& ((criterias.nationalities.Contains(p.Nationality)) || (criterias.nationalities == null))
```

criterias isa class where i store my search criterias. nationalities is a string list. the problem occurs when i have no items in string. the query throws null reference exception. the query doesnt accept null value in nationalities. how can i fix this?

Comment: Your use of `( )` is not very consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the order so that the null check comes before the query: as you're using `||`, the second part of the expression is only evaluated when the first part evaluates to false:

```
&& ((criterias.nationalities == null) || 
             (criterias.nationalities.Contains(p.Nationality)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at these 2:

```
   ((criterias.birthday == p.BirthDay|| criterias.birthday == null))
&& ((criterias.marriageDate == null || criterias.marriageDate == p.MarriageDate))
```

I don't think marriageDate  will give you problems but birthday uses the wrong order.
In this case you need the 'short-circuit evaluation' property of `||`, change it to:

```
   (criterias.birthday == null || criterias.birthday == p.BirthDay)
&& (criterias.marriageDate == null || criterias.marriageDate == p.MarriageDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try swapping the order of the nationalties checks.  It should short-circuit on the null check before it tries to evaluate the Contains.

```
((criterias.nationalities == null) || (criterias.nationalities.Contains(p.Nationality)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn this statement around:

```
(criterias.nationalities.Contains(p.Nationality)) || (criterias.nationalities == null)
```

so that it reads

```
(criterias.nationalities == null) || (criterias.nationalities.Contains(p.Nationality))
```

If the first operand evaluates to true, the second one will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Try first check for null then (if it is not null) check for contains:

```
var q = from p in query 
where     
((criterias.birthday == p.BirthDay|| criterias.birthday == null))                                 
&& ((criterias.marriageDate == null ||  criterias.marriageDate == p.MarriageDate))
&& ((criterias.gender == p.Gender) || (criterias.gender == null)) 
&& ((criterias.nationalities == null) || (criterias.nationalities.Contains(p.Nationality))
```

Comment: I changed the order of null check and contains. And I also changed "null" side as ""criterias.nationalities.count == 0"". Then it worked. Thanks for help